# CSS Write additional class properties based on inline class condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a little code below.  When I click on the button, my class `square` will have an inline style `<div class="square" style="display: block;"></div>`

Based on this inside style, I will have some more properties for the class `square` such as: `left: 0`.  In other words, when class `square` has a `style="display: block;"`, I need to have more stylings for it.  But I don't know how to write more CSS on this situation.

**NOTE**: I know I could write more class properties inside this javascript for what I need, but in this case, this javascript function is not on my hand.  My job is to add more properties style when the `square` has `style="display: block;"`

Please give a hand.  Thanks!

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    $('.square').css('display', 'block');
  })
})
```

```css
.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: gray;
  position: absolute;
  left: -100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
<div class="square"></div>
</div>
<button>Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a class with selector `.square[style="display: block;"]` and the desired properties (I added a red border for demonstration purposes in my snippet below) to your stylesheet which will be applied automatically when the element gets that inline `style="display: block;"` attribute on clicking the button:

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    $('.square').css('display', 'block');
  })
})
```

```css
.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: gray;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
}
.square[style="display: block;"] {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="square"></div>
<button>Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Hi Johannes, Thank you very much for your help, it works as expected!  I just voted your answer as my appreciation!  Another thing I forgot to mention yesterday, how can I add more style for `square`'s parent when `style="display: block;"` shows up?  Please give a hand.

Comment: There is no parent selector in CSS, so you have to do that with JS/jQuery